# Issue in Redirecting onActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 methods for session expiry checking first 1 for Controller and 2nd for API Controller ...i have an issue in redirecting i tried many ways but unable to redirect ... the code is given below ..

```
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        // check  sessions here

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.SessionKeys.UserId] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "HomeController" }, { "action", "Redirect" } });
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

  public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {

        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check  sessions here
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.SessionKeys.UserId] == null)
        {
            System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filtercontext = new System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext();
            filtercontext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult("http://a830edad9050849NDA3307.sharepoint.com/sites/SPBoxUI");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
```

In the first one i have an Action in controller and also place a break point over there but i think that is not being called.I am using MVC4 Both of these does not work as Expected ...Thanks in Advance for kind Help

Answer (score 0):

Try like following. This snippet may help you.

```
Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Redirect", "Home"));
```